Calculate value based on sum of previous calculated values
What needs to happen: create a new column called AdjustedAllocation by taking the IncrementedSourceRatio and multiplying it by the original AllocationAmount LESS the SUM of all previous AdjustedAllocation for that participant.
Issue is that I'm referencing the value I'm trying to calculate in the same column. And I need all the prior calculated values to make the correct adjustment. The last column is the expected value.



(A) PlanID
(B) EEID
(C) TotalBalance
(D) Ticker
(E) MarketValue
(F) CurrentDenominator
(G) AllocationAmount
(H) IncrementedSourceRatio
(I) Adjusted Allocation Formula
(J) Adjusted Allocation




10241299
11973
241781.86
VEMAX
5654.12
241781.86
1
0.0233
=H2*G2
0.0233


10241299
11973
241781.86
VMGMX
5972.14
236127.74
1
0.0252
=H3*(G3-J2)
0.02461284


10241299
11973
241781.86
VTMGX
35099.02
230155.6
1
0.1525
=H4*(G4-(J2+J3))
0.1451932919


10241299
11973
241781.86
VTSAX
45529.07
195056.58
1
0.2334
=H5*(G5-(J2+J3+J4))
0.18832902881454


10241299
11973
241781.86
VFIAX
149527.51
149527.51
1
1
=H6*(G6-(J2+J3+J4+J5))
0.61856483928546



I've tried variations of LAG(), SUM(), COALESCE(), adding ROW_NUMBER(), and all kinds of temp tables to no avail.
I've narrowed it down to some kind of recursive query/CTE, but most of the examples I have found are very simple and don't exactly fit what I'm trying to do. I'm still trying to learn how to apply CTEs and I'm hoping seeing a solution for this item will help solidify my understanding.
These solutions came close, but not exactly what I need to accomplish:

SQL Server - How to get running cummulative difference with certain condition
SQL get difference between rows values?
SQL recursive calculate based on previous calculation

Thank you in advance for helping my learning.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP', 'u') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP2', 'u') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP2
GO

CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    PlanID NVARCHAR(10)
    ,EEID NVARCHAR(15)
    ,Ticker NVARCHAR(10)
    ,MarketValue MONEY
    ,TotalBalance MONEY
    ,CurrentDenominator MONEY
    ,AllocationAmount DECIMAL(18,6)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES
('10241299',    '70973',    'VEMAX',    5654.12,    241781.86,  241781.86,  1),
('10241299',    '70973',    'VMGMX',    5972.14,    241781.86,  236127.74,  1),
('10241299',    '70973',    'VTMGX',    35099.02,   241781.86,  230155.6,   1),
('10241299',    '70973',    'VTSAX',    45529.07,   241781.86,  195056.58,  1),
('10241299',    '70973',    'VFIAX',    149527.51,  241781.86,  149527.51,  1)

SELECT
    PlanID 
    ,EEID 
    ,TotalBalance 
    ,Ticker
    ,MarketValue 
    ,CurrentDenominator 
    ,AllocationAmount
    ,IncrementedSourceRatio = (MarketValue/CurrentDenominator)
INTO #TEMP2
FROM #TEMP

SELECT
    PlanID 
    ,EEID 
    ,TotalBalance 
    ,Ticker
    ,MarketValue 
    ,CurrentDenominator 
    ,AllocationAmount
    ,IncrementedSourceRatio
FROM #TEMP2


Haw you define order of rows? Your SQL Server version is?

In this case, it would be PlanID, EEID, MarketValue, Ticker... My SQL Server version is 19.1.56.0

I think, calculations thru window functions (LAG,LEAD, ...)  much more difficult, if at all possible.

You can use a recursion. First you should define a column to order your rows, MarketValue I guess. So add     ,rn = row_number() over(order by MarketValue) to your #temp2 query and than
with rcte as (
    select *
      ,cast(IncrementedSourceRatio * AllocationAmount as DECIMAL(10,9)) AdjustedAllocation
      ,cast(0 as DECIMAL(10,9)) cumulAA
    from #temp2 
    where rn=1

    union all

    select t2.*
      ,cast(t2.IncrementedSourceRatio * (t2.AllocationAmount - rcte.cumulAA - rcte.AdjustedAllocation) as DECIMAL(10,9))
      ,cast(rcte.cumulAA + rcte.AdjustedAllocation as DECIMAL(10,9))
    from rcte
    join #temp2 t2 on t2.rn= rcte.rn+1
  )
select *
from rcte
order by MarketValue;

Returns
PlanID  EEID    TotalBalance    Ticker  MarketValue AllocationAmount    IncrementedSourceRatio  rn  AdjustedAllocation  cumulAA
10241299    70973   241781.8600 VEMAX   5654.1200   1.000000    0.0233  1   0.023300000 0.000000000
10241299    70973   241781.8600 VMGMX   5972.1400   1.000000    0.0252  2   0.024612840 0.023300000
10241299    70973   241781.8600 VTMGX   35099.0200  1.000000    0.1525  3   0.145193290 0.047912840
10241299    70973   241781.8600 VTSAX   45529.0700  1.000000    0.2334  4   0.188329030 0.193106130
10241299    70973   241781.8600 VFIAX   149527.5100 1.000000    1.0000  5   0.618564840 0.381435160

db-fiddle

You're looking for a Windowed Function.
MyRunningTotal = SUM([Col1]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Col2] ORDER BY [Col3])

You could also use functions like LAG() or LEAD(). Examples can be found here, as well as another way to accomplish this. As with most things in programming, there are lots of ways to go about it.

The issue I ran into when trying to use a windowed function like this is the formula requires the sum of the result(s) of the calculation before it. I got errors when I tried to "self reference."

The simplest case, in my opinion, is recursive calculation.
The possibility of calculating through window functions requires careful consideration.
See example
-- with float(53)
with t as(select row_number()over(order by PlanID, EEID, MarketValue, Ticker)rn
  ,cast(AllocationAmount as float(53)) G, cast(IncrementedSourceRatio as float(53)) H
 ,CheckValue T
from #temp2
)
,r as(
  select  rn,G, H, H*G as I
     ,H*G as s
     ,T
  from t where rn=1
  union all
  select  t.rn,t.G,t.H,t.H*(t.G-r.s) as I
     ,t.H*(t.G-r.s) + r.s as s
     ,t.T
  from r inner join t on t.rn=(r.rn+1)
)
select * from r;

Calculation process (for float(53)). There T -(J) Adjusted Allocation for check.



rn
G
H
I
s
T




1
1.000000
0.0233
0.0233
0.0233
0.0233


2
1.000000
0.0252
0.02461284
0.04791284
0.02461284


3
1.000000
0.1525
0.1451932919
0.1931061319
0.1451932919


4
1.000000
0.2334
0.18832902881454
0.38143516071454
0.18832902881454


5
1.000000
1.0000
0.61856483928546
1
0.61856483928546



Demo
I did not consider the accuracy of the calculations.

Like you guessed, you need to use recursion to solve it. Another potential solution might be using correlated subqueries but I'll not dive into that now.
A challenge with the sample dataset you've provided is that it has no ordinal value that identifies the order of rows. Rows in SQL have no order implicitly and your dataset does not include a serial number or something like a date/timestamp that I can use to generate a serial number. I am assuming that the original, full dataset has some provision to solve this - so I've explicitly added a serial number column SerialNum
Here is the solution using recursive CTEs
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    *
    , ROUND(1.0 * MarketValue / CurrentDenominator, 4) AS IncrementedSourceRatio
  FROM
    raw_data
)
  
, recursive AS (
  SELECT
    SerialNum, PlanID, EEID, Ticker, MarketValue, TotalBalance, CurrentDenominator, AllocationAmount
    , IncrementedSourceRatio
    , CAST(0 AS FLOAT) AS AdjustedAllocationPrevCumSum
    , CAST(IncrementedSourceRatio * AllocationAmount AS FLOAT) AS AdjustedAllocation
  FROM
    dataset
  WHERE
    SerialNum = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    D.SerialNum, D.PlanID, D.EEID, D.Ticker, D.MarketValue, D.TotalBalance, D.CurrentDenominator, D.AllocationAmount
    , D.IncrementedSourceRatio
    , CAST(R.AdjustedAllocationPrevCumSum + R.AdjustedAllocation AS FLOAT) AS AdjustedAllocationPrevCumSum
    , CAST(D.IncrementedSourceRatio * (D.AllocationAmount - (R.AdjustedAllocationPrevCumSum + R.AdjustedAllocation)) AS FLOAT) AS AdjustedAllocation
  FROM
    recursive AS R
  INNER JOIN
    dataset AS D ON (
      R.SerialNum = D.SerialNum - 1
    )
)
SELECT
  SerialNum, PlanID, EEID, Ticker, MarketValue, TotalBalance, CurrentDenominator
  , AllocationAmount
  , IncrementedSourceRatio
  , AdjustedAllocation
FROM recursive

We define a column AdjustedAllocationPrevCumSum to keep track of the cumulative sum of AjustedAllocation values till the immediately previous record.
Then AdjustedAllocation for each record = IncrementedSourceRatio * (AllocationAmount - (AdjustedAllocationPrevCumSum + AdjustedAllocation of previous record))
Output is as expected.
Here is the DB Fiddle.
